# Blocking IP addresses, preventing DoS attacks

Tags: denial-of-service

So this is more of a general question on the best practice of preventing DoS attacks, I'm just trying to get a grasp on how most people handle malicious requests from the same IP address which is the problem we are currently having.

I figure it's better to block the IP of a truly malicious IP as high up as possible as to prevent using more resources, especially when it comes to loading you application.

Thoughts?

Comment: I wonder if this might be a better question for the ServerFault site?

Comment: This isn't programming-related, and is off topic here.

Comment: you can also try mod_qos, mod_evasive if you are using apache, you should read http://weblogs.asp.net/omarzabir/archive/2007/10/16/prevent-denial-of-service-dos-attacks-in-your-web-application.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can prevent DoS attacks from occuring in various ways.

- Limiting the number of queries/second
  from a particular ip address. Once
  the limit is reached, you can send a
  redirect to a cached error page to
  limit any further processing. You
  might also be able to get these IP
  address firewalled so that you don't
  have to process their requests at
  all. Limiting requests per IP address
  wont work very well though if the
  attacker forges the source IP address
  in the packets they are sending.
- I'd also be trying to build some
  smarts into your application to help
  dealing with a DoS. Take Google maps
  as an example. Each individual site
  has to have it's own API key which I
  believe is limited to 50,000 requests
  per day. If your application worked
  in a similar way, then you'd want to
  validate this key very early on in
  the request so that you don't use too
  many resources for the request. Once
  the 50,000 requests for that key are
  used, you can send appropriate proxy
  headers such that all future requests
  (for the next hour for example) for
  that key are handled by the reverse
  proxy. It's not fool proof though. If
  each request has a different url,
  then the reverse proxy will have to
  pass through the request to the
  backend server. You would also run
  into a problem if the DDOS used lots
  of different API keys.
- Depending on the target audience for
  your application, you might be able
  to black list large IP ranges that
  contribute significantly to the DDOS.
  For example, if your web service is
  for Australian's only, but you were
  getting a lot of DDOS requests from
  some networks in Korea, then you
  could firewall the Korean networks.
  If you want your service to be
  accessible by anyone, then you're out
  of luck on this one.
- Another approach to dealing with a DDOS is to
  close up shop and wait it out. If
  you've got your own IP address or IP
  range then you, your hosting company
  or the data centre can null route the
  traffic so that it goes into a block
  hole.

Referenced from [here](http://www.webhostingtalk.com.au/general-discussion-2/handling-dos-attacks-9196.html). There are other solutions too on same thread.

Comment: Hey, Awesome tips, I like the idea of actually using a firewall... I was always under the impression that firewalls where for corporate email servers or something... haha. I suppose they do have a purpose. Thanks!

Comment: It seem like a fire wall might have an option to only allow X number of requests per hour,day, etc from a given IP address. I'm no firewall expert. Do anyone know if these types of rules are something a firewall would commonly handle?

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 -m statistic --probability 0.5 -j DROP iptables -I INPUT n -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 -m rpfilter --loose -j ACCEPT
# n would be an numeric index into the INPUT CHAIN -- default is append to INPUT chain
```

more at...
[Can't Access Plesk Admin Because Of DOS Attack, Block IP Address Through SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301411/cant-access-plesk-admin-because-of-dos-attack-block-ip-address-through-ssh/13735926#13735926)