# Can't Access Plesk Admin Because Of DOS Attack, Block IP Address Through SSH?

Tags: apache, ssh, plesk, ddos, denial-of-service

I can't access Plesk Amdin because of DOS attack; can I block a hostname or IP address through SSH?  If so, how would I be able to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you have iptables you can block it using simple rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT --source 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
```

This rule drops packets coming from IP 1.2.3.4.

Comment: Your answer was really helpful for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest is to SSH to your box use vim to and add the following to the top of your .htaccess file in the root of your domain (`/var/www/vhosts/yourdomain.com/httpdocs/.htaccess`):

```
deny from 12.345.67.89
```

Obviously replace the IP address with the one you want to block. Repeat this for any sites you think are being attacked.

Answer (score 0):

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 -m statistic --probability 0.5 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT n -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 -m rpfilter --loose -j ACCEPT    # n would be an numeric index into the INPUT CHAIN -- default is append to INPUT chain

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp  -m hashlimit --hashlimit-mode srcip  -s 1.2.3.4 --hashlimit-srcmask  --hashlimit-above 9/second  -j DROP

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 -m limit --sport 80 --limit 100/second -j ACCEPT

There are countless others for your circumstances.

Sincerely,

ArrowInTree